# I'm attempting to execute a Flask test file, but when attempting to access it through the browser, an error stating that the site cannot be reached

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I have tried creating an inbound rule in my firewall to allow port <5000> but its still showing site cannot be reached.
i have also tried to Check UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) with this command

'''sudo ufw status'''
'''sudo ufw allow 5000 '''

but still am getting the same error on my browser, site cannot be reached. Am using Vagrant as my environment

Comment: The question is missing important information - from which machine do you try to access the Flask application? From within the same network or an external network?

Comment: within the same network

Comment: Please do not put additional information in comments but edit them into your post!
Please also add to your questions: a) how to do start Flask? b) which output do you get after starting Flask? c) which error do you get in the browser?